# symfony4, Dependency injection, no default argument

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have setup service to controller function like this

```
App\Controller\Controller:
    calls:
        - [new, ['@request_stack','@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']]
```

I needed `Entity Manager` inside controller action and my function looks like this

```
public function new(RequestStack $request, EntityManager $em): Response
{
    $currentRequest = $request->getCurrentRequest();
    $data = json_decode($currentRequest->getContent(), true);
    ....
    return new ApiResponse(['message' => $message['message'], 'body' => 'success']);
}
```

and when executing comes to line `return new ApiResponse` it gives error

```
Controller "Controller::new()" requires that you provide a value for the "$request" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.
```

How to get entity manager in controller action or how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Symfony 4 Doc on Doctrine says :

```
// you can fetch the EntityManager via $this->getDoctrine()
// or you can add an argument to your action: index(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

So you can just get the entity manager this way in your controller

However, you can also register the Entity Manager as a service to use it.

Be sure to set the autowire to true :

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
```

and register it as a service :

```
   # config/services.yaml
   services:
     #....
        controller_em:
            class: App\Controller\Controller
            arguments: [ '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager' ]
            public: true
```

So that you can use it like so in your controller :

```
private $objectManager;

public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
{
    $this->objectManager = $objectManager;

}
```

You can also use this way to use the Entity Manager in Voter or Manager.

Comment: you are not getting `Entity Manager` using `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` but `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry`

Comment: i got confused by my ide PHPStrom i got working all this $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()

Answer (score 0):

well. you need to inject your stuff into controller's object constructor - that is called [DI](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html) in Symfony-way (or via set-methods):

services.yml - if everything ok with your [autowire](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html)

```
App\Controller\Controller:
    calls:
        - [new]
```

if not add it manually:

```
 App\Controller\Controller:
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'
    calls:
        - [new]
```

Controller.php

```
/** @var EntityManager */
private $em;

public __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

and then just use it in your method:

```
public function new(RequestStack $request): Response
{
    $this->em ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your information you can create your own AbsractController to inject the EntityManager in all controller extending it like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController as BaseController;

abstract class AbstractController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * @required
     *
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function setEntityManager(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

If a controller extends this AbstractController, you could access $this->em everywhere in it.

The "required" annotation here is the key to enable what you tried to do without the need of adding configuration as you did. It's like adding a calls line in your configuration!

You could do something like this for every services you need in all your controllers.